# How do I set a different Python version in my environment from my base environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, databricks

My base environment's Python version is the 3.7, the way I like it. However, I need to create a new environment that uses Python version 3.5.

I created my environment specifying version 3.5:
`conda create --name dbconnect python=3.5`

However, when I activate my environment (`conda activate dbconnect`) and check for the python version (`python --version`), I get

```
(dbconnect) computer-name:src vivian$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

I tried downgrading the Python version in the `dbconnect` environment by running `conda install python=3.5` and get this

```
(dbconnect) computer-name:src vivian$ conda install python=3.5
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

It appears to have worked but it hasn't because when I check the Python version, it is still 3.7.3

```
(dbconnect) computer-name:src vivian$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

The only way to have my `dbconnect` environment have Python version 3.5 is to downgrade the Python version in my base environment, but I do not want to do that. How do I have my `dbconnect` environment use Python 3.5 and my base environment use Python 3.7?

Comment: What is the output of `type python`?

Comment: `type python` gives me `python is /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: That means you are not launching the python interpreter of your conda env but from you system. Can you try to launch the python interpreter of your dbconnect env via its absolute path?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I have an environment variable `CONDA_PYTHON_EXE` set to `/Users/my_username/anaconda3/bin/python` already. I don't even know why my computer is not launching the Python interpreter of my conda environment in the first place. I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. My environment variables were getting messed up because my `.bash_profile` was bad. Thank you!

Comment: @vivian Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

"I figured it out. My environment variables were getting messed up because my .`bash_profile` was bad".